# How to utilise the count function with regard to the map container

Tags: c++, stl, containers

So my program basically stores a student's name, id and marks and a bunch of functions to access particular data and utilize the same. I have implemented two classes. `Student` consists of basic information while `table` mainly consists of the member's functions I'm using and the `map` container.

Since the key of my `map` is an object, I added a boolean operator such that it sorts the names by ID. Now, my question is with regard  to the search by ID function where  I input a user ID and it print's out the corresponding marks. I wanted to utilize the function

`int count(const K & k) const`;

Since I only have only have the ID and not the name, will I still be able to utilize the same?

```
class student{
public:
    student();
    student(int,string);
    int id;
    string name;
};

class table{
public:
    void InsertStudent(student x, int y);
    void PrintAll(table t);
    void SearchbyID(student x);
    void SearchbyGrade(int y);
    void SortbyGrade(table t);

private:
    map<student, int > records;

};

//For map key
bool operator<(const student &a , const student & b){
    return a.id<b.id;
}
```

Comment: What is the `records` map actually *mapping*? Does it map a `student` to an id? That makes no sense, why not map the id to a `student`?

Comment: It's mapping a students name and id to his or her grade.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Then as for your problem, either you have to initialize a temporary `student` object that you pass to the `count` function. Or use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) with a custom predicate (e.g. a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)) to compare.

Comment: If I initialize a temporary student object without a name and just the ID, will it still be able to locate the student?

Comment: I would use find.  It's not a multimap, so your choices are 0 or 1 students with that id in the map so they will either be found or not.

Comment: If you try, does it work? If it uses the existing `<` comparison function (which it should do IIRC) then it should "just work", otherwise you will get an error saying the there's no `==` operator defined for the `student` class (in which case you can simply implement one to compare only the id).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! It seems to work fine. However, if I want to print the name along with the grade(Name is a part of the key), since I'm not using an iterator to run through the map, is there any way I can output the name part of the key?

Comment: Then use `find` as suggested by @RetiredNinja. That will return an iterator to the found entry, which contains both the key and the data.